# How do I remove certain values from a file reader (utilizing an ArrayList)?

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList <String> farmAnimals = new ArrayList 

try {
    String stringCurrentLine;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/myUser/Downloads/farmAnimals.txt"));
        while ((stringCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            farmAnimals.add(stringCurrentLine);
        }
```

After coding a for loop, it is printing out the list of farm animals like this:

```
 1. Pig
 2. Sheep
 3. Cow
 4. Horse
```

Is there a method where I can trim each String value as to where the numbers are gone and I just get the text values?

Comment: Split on space  / substring with index of '.' / regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have severals options, all before adding the line to the list :

1. Split on the space between the number and the word (Only if there is one word)

   ```
   stringCurrentLine = stringCurrentLine.trim().split("\\s+")[1];
   ```
2. Use `String.substring()` method :

   ```
   stringCurrentLine=stringCurrentLine.substring(stringCurrentLine.indexOf('.')+1).trim();
   ```
3. Use a `regex` but it would be too much for that simple case